# gdb debug using eclipse CDT: not able to show correctly varibles values

Tags: c, eclipse, debugging, gdb, eclipse-cdt

I'm debugging a C application using eclipse CDT. Generally I can go up in breakpoints and also step by step. But the problem is that I have problem to see the variable in steps. But if I want to see the content of a char** variable called path_list, I see in the variables window this error:

```
Failed to execute MI command:
-data-evaluate-expression *(*(path_list))
Error message from debugger back end: 
value has been optimized out
```

So I tried to see the memory content of the variable path_list but I got an error popup:

[image]

Has someone an idea about this problem and how I can see the content of path_list?

Comment: If the variable indeed has been optimized out you won't be able to get its value even under pure `gdb`.  Do you build your program without optimization (like gcc -O2 flag)?

Comment: In Project->Properties->C/C++ Build->Settings->GCC C Compiler->Optimization, what optimization level and flags are configured?

Comment: In Project->Build Configurations->Set Active, are you building a Debug version or a Release version? They use different optimization options by default.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you compiled your code with -g and -O0 options. By default compiler not uses -O0.

Comment: This is not true. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html: `-O0 -- Reduce compilation time and make debugging produce the expected results. This is the default.`